# Is there a way to permanently turn off ANSI for Composer?

Tags: shell, composer-php

When I run Composer in my shell, it renders all of the text with a background color of dark yellow, so that it is almost impossible to read.

There's an option to supply the `--no-ansi` argument with every command I run, but this really seems like a pain. Is there a way to turn it off of the default? Or even change the color to something more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that it was because I was using an "old" version of Composer. When I tried to run an install, I was getting the

```
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is
recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update"
to get the latest version.
```

I ran `self-update`, and it saw that there hadn't even been a new version in the last 30 days, but it is now rendering in a readable color scheme.

Answer (score 5):

Just to give a real answer to this question, because I still have the requirement to call composer with --no-ansi (on a Windows server), because of such output in Putty via SSH:

[image: Wrong ANSI output in Putty on Windows servers]

You can edit the batch file of composer:

```
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat
(edit its content)
php "%~dp0composer.phar" %* --no-ansi
```

Source: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19520#issuecomment-242627544