# Bash output error in the format while making new entity. Random characters appears

Tags: bash, symfony, visual-studio-code

In a symfony project i am using bash terminal integrated in VSCode. When i try to make a new entity using `$bin/console make:entity`

Random character appears in the bash.

I have updated bash to latest version but the problem is still there.

Random characters such as " `?[32m` " can be seen in the output below:

Bash Terminal Output-

```
$ php bin/console make:entity

 Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. DeliciousKangaroo):
 > BlogPost
B?[Kl?[Ko?[Kg?[KP?[Ko?[Ks?[Kt?[K

 ?[32mMark this class as an API Platform resource (expose a CRUD API for it) (yes/no)?[39m [?[33mno?[39m]:
 > yes

 ?[32mcreated?[39m: src/Entity/BlogPost.php
 ?[32mcreated?[39m: src/Repository/BlogPostRepository.php

 Entity generated! Now let's add some fields!
 You can always add more fields later manually or by re-running this command.

 ?[32mNew property name (press ?[39m?[32m<return>?[39m?[32m to stop adding fields)?[39m:
 > title

 ?[32mField type (enter ?[39m?[33m??[39m?[32m to see all types)?[39m [?[33mstring?[39m]:
 >


 ?[32mField length?[39m [?[33m255?[39m]:
 >

 ?[32mCan this field be null in the database (nullable) (yes/no)?[39m [?[33mno?[39m]:
 >

 ?[32mupdated?[39m: src/Entity/BlogPost.php

 ?[32mAdd another property? Enter the property name (or press ?[39m?[32m<return>?[39m?[32m to stop adding fields)?[39m:
 > published

 ?[32mField type (enter ?[39m?[33m??[39m?[32m to see all types)?[39m [?[33mstring?[39m]:
 > datetime
d?[K?7?[30;47matetime?[39;49m?8a?[K?7?[30;47mtetime?[39;49m?8t?[K?7?[30;47metime?[39;49m?8e?[K?7?[30;47mtime?[39;49m?8t?[K?7?[30;47mime?[39;49m?8i?[K?7?[30;47mme?[39;49m?8m?[K?7?[30;47me?[39;49m?8e?[K?7?8

 ?[32mCan this field be null in the database (nullable) (yes/no)?[39m [?[33mno?[39m]:
 >
```

Comment: Please don't use unneccesary tagging - is this question in any way related to node.js or bash?

Comment: those [32m stuff is probably some control codes to color the output, which obviously is not working as intended. the point is, color codes must be supported by the terminal (the thing running bash). and some terminals just don't. I'm not sure how to signal to symfony console, that colors aren't supported.

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091457/is-there-a-way-to-permanently-turn-off-ansi-for-composer you can run your commands with additional `--no-ansi` to disable the codes temporarily but the answers also show ways to make this more permanent.

Comment: @Nico Hasse i m sorry for using node.js tag. I thought it is relevant to it. But yes it is related to bash. Since it is the output from bash terminal

Comment: Thank you Jakumi.. i will look into it.. i got your point